# How to add some extra data to an existing file using node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, xmlnode

I have a file like This

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Quiz>
<title>Matching</title>

/* Rewrite */
<questions>
<question>Can be passed on from the environment to the individual. This can be from a person, insects or from the physical environment. </question>
<answer>Communicable</answer>
</questions>
/* Rewrite End */

</quiz>
```

Now  i want to add some data before  `</quiz>` tag so it will look like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Quiz>
<title>Matching</title>


<questions>
<question>Can be passed on from the environment to the individual. This can be from a person, insects or from the physical environment. </question>
<answer>Communicable</answer>
</questions>

<questions>
<question>Some Txt</question>
<answer>Some Txt</answer>
</questions>


</quiz>
```

I am using

```
fs.writeFile("Templatexml.xml", data["message"] , function(err) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("The file was saved!");
  }
});
```

It fully rewrites the file every time I want to read the file and and write the extra content on this file how can i do this?

Comment: IMHO this isn't a duplicate, as the other question is about appending to the *end* of a file, this question is about inserting something into the *middle* of a file.

Comment: i want to add data  in between the Existing data. i dont know how can i do that. so only i opened a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a kind of hacky solution for your problem..
format you xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Quiz>
<title>Matching</title>
/* Rewrite */
<questions>
<question>Can be passed on from the environment to the individual. This can be from    person, insects or from the physical environment. </question>
<answer>Communicable</answer>
</questions>
//cursor
</quiz>
```

and the code for appending new data:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var addData = "<questions><question>Some Txt</question><answer>Some Txt</answer>     </questions>";
var cursor = "//cursor";
addData += cursor;
fs.readFile("Templatexml.xml", "utf-8",function(err,data) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
     }
    var newData = data.replace(/\/\/cursor/,addData);
    fs.writeFile("Templatexml.xml", newData , function(err) {
    if(err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
     } 
     console.log("done");
    });
});
```